# Alternatives of a poor sentence, "Summer is increasing day by day."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, alternatives

Today I have come across a sentence that seems quite poor:

> Summer is **increasing** day by day.

The word *increasing* doesn't seem to be suitable here. Tell me the alternatives for this.

Is it okay to say:

> Winter is **letting up.**

Thank you.

Comment: What happened to spring?

Comment: Maybe ”Summer is getting closer” or ”Summer is coming”?

Answer (score 1):

"Winter is letting up" is fine. That means that it is getting ***less wintry***, the weather is less characteristic of winter. You can say "getting ***more summery*** day by day", but *summery* is not as widely accepted as wintry, in my experience. So a safer option might be:

> It's feeling **more like summer** every day.